# Триггер на обновление связанной таблицы mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, триггер

Имеется два отношения
BOOKS:

[image: отношение BOOKS]

BOOKS_LIKES:

[image: отношение BOOKS_LIKES]

Необходимо написать триггер, который будет менять count_likes по id в отношении BOOKS при добавлении или удалении записей в BOOKS_LIKES

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так, делайте такой запрос, когда счётчик должен **уменьшиться**:

```
UPDATE `BOOKS` SET `count_likes` = `count_likes` - 1 WHERE `id_books` = <BOOK_ID>
```

И этот запрос, когда счётчик должен **увеличиться**:

```
UPDATE `BOOKS` SET `count_likes` = `count_likes` + 1 WHERE `id_books` = <BOOK_ID>
```

Вместе BOOK_ID подставьте нужный ID книги.